# Django http request to api error

Tags: python, django

As this is the first time I'm trying this out, I do not know what is wrong with the problem. So it would be great if someone can help me solve this problem

The code I'm using is at the bottom page of this website: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/11/build-your-own-pokedex-with-django-mms-and-pokeapi.html

Where it give example on how you can make HTTP request function and retrieve database on your query.

The code on the website is this.

**query.py**

```
import requests
import json

BASE_URL = 'http://pokeapi.co'


def query_pokeapi(resource_url):
    url = '{0}{1}'.format(BASE_URL, resource_url)
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response.text)
    return None


charizard = query_pokeapi('/api/v1/pokemon/charizard/')

sprite_uri = charizard['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']
description_uri = charizard['descriptions'][0]['resource_uri']

sprite = query_pokeapi(sprite_uri)
description = query_pokeapi(description_uri)

print
charizard['name']
print
description['description']
print
BASE_URL + sprite['image']
```

In my edit, I only change these print line at the bottom of this

**query.py**

```
print(charizard['name'])
print(description['description'])
print(BASE_URL + sprite['image'])
```

But i got this error instead

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "query2.py", line 46, in
>   
>       sprite_uri = charizard['sprites'][0]['resource_uri'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

query_pokeapi must be returning None, which would mean that your API call is not receiving a 200 HTTP response. I'd check your URL, to make sure it's properly formed. Test it in your web browser.

best practice would be to try-except your API call with an error message letting you know that your API call failed and otherwise routing the thread.

Update: reread and the sub scripting issue could be in any layer of your nested object.

Evaluate charizard['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']
step by step in your debugger.

Answer (score 1):

When you call api `requests.get(url)` then its response is

> More than one resource is found at this URI

you are using `charizard['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']` on result and it's raising exception.

When I tried to get response then status code is `300` so

`def query_pokeapi(resource_url)` returning `None` value.

```
'{0}{1}'.format(BASE_URL, resource_url)
```

**Update**

it means at `{0}` `BASE_URL` will be places and at `{1}` resource_url will  be places.

Complete url will be

```
url = '{0}{1}'.format(BASE_URL, resource_url)
url = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/charizard/'.
```

**update**

you can try

```
import json
charizard = query_pokeapi('/api/v1/pokemon/')
data = json.loads(charizard.content)
print data['objects'][0]['descriptions'][0]
```

result will be

```
{u'name': u'ekans_gen_1', u'resource_uri': u'/api/v1/description/353/'}
```

**Update with complete code**

```
import requests
import json

BASE_URL = 'http://pokeapi.co'


def query_pokeapi(resource_url):
    url = '{0}{1}'.format(BASE_URL, resource_url)
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response.text)
    return None

charizard = query_pokeapi('/api/v1/pokemon/')
print charizard['objects'][0]['descriptions'][0]
```

result will be:

```
{u'name': u'ekans_gen_1', u'resource_uri': u'/api/v1/description/353/'}
```

Comment: Ah, i see. May i ask about what does `'{0}{1}'` and `(resource_url)` mean in the `def query_pokeapi(resource_url)` ?

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't the `def query_pokeapi(resource_url)` function be put below ? or the order of the code doesn't matter ?

Comment: Oh, as for this `sprite_uri = charizard['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']`  does it means it add up to the url ? to bocome this `http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/charizard/sprites` ?

Comment: there is no issue in code, you just need to update URL.

Comment: I still get this,  `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'`

Comment: i use that complete code, still get this `File "query2.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(charizard['objects'][0]['descriptions'][0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`